# Происходит ли вообще обращение к конструктору класса Object?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Возник достаточно интересный вопрос, на который я пока не смог найти ответ, но уверен, что здесь мне помогут.

Все мы прекрасно знаем о том, что при создании экземпляра класса в памяти у нас осуществляется вызов конструктора, после чего будет создан сам объект. Выполнение кода внутри конструктора сопряжено с инициализацией полей нашего объекта (не статические поля) и вызовом одного из родительских конструкторов (в том случае, если мы не вызываем другой конструктор из того же класса при помощи ключевого слова `this`).

Вот тут мы и подходим к сути вопроса. Допустим, что у нас имеется какой-нибудь произвольный класс, который не наследуется явным образом от какого бы то ни было существующего класса. Что это для нас означает в плане наследования? Это означает то, что класс будет наследоваться напрямую от корневого класса (пусть даже неявно), которым в языке программирования Java является класс `Object`.

Меня немного смущает тот факт, что в нашем произвольном классе мы можем описать конструктор с любым количеством и типами входных параметров (их порядок в коде также может быть каким угодно), в то время, как в самом классе `Object` имеется всего лишь один единственный конструктор, который не принимает никаких параметров.

Собственно сам вопрос. Происходит ли вообще обращение к конструктору класса `Object`? Если да, то значит ли это, что всё время вызывается один и тот же конструктор, который не принимает никаких параметров на вход? Или же на основании конструктора наследника автоматически создаётся аналогичный по набору входных параметров конструктор, только уже для класса `Object`?

Да и вообще, правильно ли я понимаю, что при вызове конструктора у класса `Object` уже не идёт вызов конструктора суперкласса, как это происходит со всеми другими классами (по той простой причине, что класс `Object` является корневым классом и является единственным классом в языке программирования Java, который не имеет предков, как прямых, так и косвенных)?

Comment: а зачем переоткрывать? у кого-то назрел замечательный ответ на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Происходит ли вообще обращение к конструктору класса Object?

Да, это прописано в спецификации Java ([§8.8.7. Тело конструктора](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.
>
> Если тело конструктора не начинается с явного вызова конструктора [this или super] и заданный конструктор не является частью первоначального класса `Object`, то тело конструктора неявно начинается с вызова конструктора суперкласса `super();` — выполнения конструктора без аргументов непосредственного класса-предка

Также в п. [§8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) указывается, что у каждого класса есть конструктор по умолчанию, даже если он не указан явно.

Это означает, что такой код:

```
class Test {
}
```

эквивалентен такому:

```
class Test {
     Test() {
          super(); //вызов конструктора Object
     }
}
```

И конструктор класса, который наследуется от `Object` будет вызывать конструктор `Object`.

> ... правильно ли я понимаю, что при вызове конструктора у класса Object уже не идёт вызов конструктора суперкласса, как это происходит со всеми другими классами (по той простой причине, что класс Object является корневым классом и является единственным классом в языке программирования Java, который не имеет предков, как прямых, так и косвенных)?

Правильно понимаете. Предков у `Object` нет, и конструкторы вызывать не у кого. Для него явно сделано исключение в спецификации.

### Пример

Для ясности предлагаю рассмотреть что именно происходит на простом примере.

Возьмем следующий код:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
    new Object();
}
}
```

Сохраним его в файл (Test.java) и скомпилируем. Затем посмотрим какой байт-код сгенерировал компилятор (декомпилировать класс можно с помощью команды javap -c Test.class):

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  //У класса появился конструктор
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
  //Который вызывает Object."<init>" (super())
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test
       3: dup
  //При создании объекта прописывается вызов конструктора (test."<init>")
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: pop
       8: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      15: pop
      16: return
}
```

По инструкциям видно, что:

- Компилятор явно определяет для класса: (1) конструктор по-умолчанию (2) вызов конструктора родителя.
- Конструкторы на данном этапе не что иное как обычные методы, которые вызываются через invokespecial и которым даны названия недопустимые в Java (`"<init>"`), чтобы они не пересекались с другими методами.

Конструкторы (в том числе и Object) и специальные правила, относящиеся к ним, в основном существуют только на этапе компиляции. Компилятор их проверяет, обрабатывает и преобразовывает в явные инструкции вызова методов.

Выполняет инструкции в байт-коде виртуальная машина Java. Именно она определяет что произойдет при вызове `invokespecial Test."<init>"` и  `invokespecial Object."<init>"`. Разработчики виртуальных машин имеют большую свободу интерпретации этих инструкций и применяют сложные алгоритмы оптимизации выполнения кода и выделения памяти.

Comment: Очень классно расписали, огромное спасибо за это! Тем не менее, небольшой вопрос всё-таки остался, если позволите. Открыл в своей IDE файл `Object.java` (он же `java.lang.Object`), который я нашёл в архиве со всеми исходниками, которые установил на свою ЭВМ вместе с последней версией JDK. И действительно, я ещё раз убедился в том, что в этом классе объявлен всего лишь один конструктор, вот небольшой кусок исходного кода: `public Object() {}`

Comment: Больше никаких конструкторов там нет. Следовательно, мой вопрос примерно следующий. А зачем он вообще там нужен? Вопрос может показаться немного глупым, но всё же. Его оставили пустым, так как экземпляр класса `Object` не имеет никаких полей? Я так понимаю, что этот конструктор нужен лишь для того, чтобы просто создать экземпляр этого класса. Я верно рассуждаю?

Comment: И да, я кажется понял свою ошибку. Немножко неправильно размышлял, сейчас сам фактически ответил на свой вопрос. Если позволите, то сейчас распишу свой ход мыслей и закрываю эту тему. Ваш ответ наиболее полный и принёс для меня наибольшее количество пользы. Думаю, что будет вполне справедливо, если я выберу в качество лучшего ответа именно его.

Comment: Короче говоря, я почему-то думал, что если мы не используем явно инструкцию `super()` или `this()` (с определённым количеством передаваемых параметров или же без вовсе без них) в самой первой строчке кода внутри нашего конструктора, то по умолчанию (неявным для нас образом) будет вызван конструктор суперкласса с таким количеством и типами параметров (а также в том же порядке их объявления), как и у целевого конструктора из которого и совершается сам вызов. То бишь, если мы пишем что-то типа `new SomeClass(1, "java");`, то и вызов конструктора будет `super(іnt i, String message);`

Comment: Но теперь я понимаю, что ошибался. В том случае, если у нас нет явной инструкции `this` или `super` для вызова соответствующего родительского конструктора/другого конструктора из того же класса (в том случае, если будем использовать инструкцию `this`), то по умолчанию будет вызываться исключительно `super()` с пустыми параметрами (абсолютно для всех случаев). Исключением является лишь инстанцирование класса `Object`, там не будет идти обращение к конструктору суперкласса, так как класс `Object` является единственным классом в языке программирования Java, который не имеет предков.

Comment: @Lexoid Пожалуйста! Рад, что Вы разобрались. Да, конструктор суперкласса вызывается всегда и по-умолчанию только без параметров. Если конструктора без параметров в суперклассе нет, то нужный конструктор понадобится вызывать явно (иначе ошибка компиляции).

Answer (score 3):

При создании объекта всегда вызывается конструктор суперкласса. Если в конструкторе вы явно не указываете какой конструктор супер класса будет вызван, то вызовется конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров), но имей те в виду если вы создали в суперклассе конструктор с параметрами, то вам придётся определить и конструктор без параметров явно т.к. он уже будет не виден. Т.е. определив конструктор с параметрами в суперклассе и не определив в нем конструктор без параметров вы не сможете в наследнике создать объект и не указать в его конструкторе super(params) т.к. получите ошибку: в суперклассе отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию.

На счёт класса Object вы правильно понимаете конструирование любого класса заканчивается на конструкторе класса Object. Конструктор вызывается один и тот же. Параметры в вашем конструкторе нужны только вашему классу т.к. он (конструктор) инициализирует ваши переменные о которых суперкласс ничего не знает, соответственно и передавать ему их не надо. А вот если в суперклассе есть инициализируемые поля, то необходимо явно вызывать его конструктор с параметрами. Конструктора создаются один раз.

Comment: То есть, даже если я передаю конструктору, который является прямым наследником класса `Object` несколько параметров, например что-то типа: `new SomeClass("It's String!", 0);`, то даже несмотря на передачу 2-х параметров конструктору (что уже говорит о том, что мы сознательно описали в классе именно такой конструктор, который будет принимать на вход именно такое количество параметров), у нас всё равно вызовется конструктор `public Object() {}`, который задекларирован в классе `Object`?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Можете представить класс как сферу с концентрическими слоями наружный слой - ваш класс, в середине находится класс Object, а между ними классы - прослойки для каждой из которых более глубокие класс являются наследниками.  И для создания каждого слоя нужны свои конструкторы. В Java есть такое понятие как отношение классов is-a (является), наследование отражает это отношение: класс наследник is-a суперкласс, следовательно, чтобы создать класс надо создать поочередно все его суперклассы начиная с класса Object. При этом суперклассы ничего о наследниках не знают.

Comment: Ни о конструкторах, ни о параметрах, ни об инициализируемых полях. Это наследники явно или неявно вызывают конструктора суперклассов.

Answer (score 1):

> Происходит ли вообще обращение к конструктору класса `Object`?

Конечно происходит, поскольку в каждом классе есть конструктор, заданный явно или не явно.

> значит ли это, что всё время вызывается один и тот же конструктор, который не принимает никаких параметров на вход?

Конструктор родительского класса вызывается независимо от того используете вы конструктор с параметрами или без.

> правильно ли я понимаю, что при вызове конструктора у класса `Object` уже не идёт вызов конструктора суперкласса

Нет, неправильно. Сначала вызывается конструктор суперкласса, а потом конструктор подкласса. Если в классе есть конструктор, то он вызывается - если нет, то создаётся конструктор по умолчанию, который тоже вызывается, но вы этого не видите.

Comment: Немного не понял ответ по последнему вопросу. Как у класса `Object` может вызываться конструктор суперкласса, если у него никак не может быть суперкласса (это можно проверить, если вызвать на экземпляре класса `Object` цепочку из методов `getClass()` и `getSuperclass()`, которые возвратят `null`, если их вызвать на объекта класса `Object`), потому как данный класс является корневым классом в языке программирования Java. Благодарю за разъяснения!

Comment: Мне тоже не совсем понятен твой вопрос если ты говоришь о конструктора суперкласса класса Object. Или ты что-то напутал сказав *суперкласса*, а имел ввиду *подкласс*?